# How to read Blockchain Data ( .dat and .ldb files )?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin

Bitcoin Core downloads two directories : /blocks and /chainstate.

/block have a .dat file , /chainstate have a .ldb file.

How can i read these files?*
I need to have info about all transactions and address amount.

1. address 1 -> amount -> address 2
2. address 3 : amount3

Other info in block don't interest me.

---

*API blockchain.info or other API don't intrest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is to use the Bitcoin RPC API:

1. Configure the Bitcoin Core daemon by going to your Bitcoin Core app > Options > Open Configuration File.
2. Inside the bitcoin.conf file, write (and change your_user and your_password):

```
server=1
rpcuser=your_user
rpcpassword=your_password
txindex=1
```

3. Close and save the file.
4. Reboot the Bitcoin Core app.

Now you are able to use one API such as https://github.com/jgarzik/python-bitcoinrpc.

To get block transaction hashes, you can use the command `getblock`.

For example:

```
rpc_connection = AuthServiceProxy("http://%s:%s@127.0.0.1:8332" % ("your_user", "your_password"), timeout=100000)
block = rpc_connection.getblock("00000000c937983704a73af28acdec37b049d214adbda81d7e2a3dd146f6ed09")
```

To get "all" the information about one transaction (addresses, fees, etc.), you can use `getrawtransaction`.

For example:

```
raw_transaction = rpc_connection.getrawtransaction("717722008a4e134f78910b37e12dd2cf6301cb8bd2d6278d3086035bfafd4e80", 2)
```

For more information on how to use the Bitcoin RPC API, please visit https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/index.html

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev build-essential g++ libboost-all-dev libsparsehash-dev git-core perl

git clone git://github.com/znort987/blockparser.git

cd blockparser && make
```

https://github.com/znort987/blockparser

Comment: This project hasn't been updated in seven years. Is there a more current equivalent?